# How do I synchronize a method that returns a Future?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, future

Here's a stripped down version of my code.

```
public synchronized ListenableFuture<Result> getOrCreateResult() {
  Optional<Result> optionalResult = getResult();
  
  return optionalResult
      .map(Futures::immediateFuture)
      .orElseGet(this::createResult);
}

private ListenableFuture<Result> createResult() {
  return FluentFutures.from(this::futureComputation1)
      .transformAsync(this::futureComputation2, executor)
      .transformAsync(this::futureComputation3, executor)
      ...
      .transform(someComputution -> {
        Result result = buildResult();
        return result;
      }, executor);
}
```

When 2 threads call `getOrCreateResult()` , the `synchronized` block is preventing them from both entering `getOrCreateResult()` at the same time, but `buildResult()` is being called twice.

My understanding is that since `getOrCreateResult()` returns a future, as soon as the 1st thread returns the `ListenableFuture` that will eventually build the result, it gives up the lock before actually building the result. That now allows 2nd thread to enter `getOrCreateResult()`. If 1st thread has not executed the `buildResult()`, then the 2nd thread will get an empty `optionalResult` and will attempt to call `buildResult()` too.

What do I need to do to ensure `buildResult()` is only called once?

Comment: You can call `Future.get()` inside the synchronized code to make sure it completes before exiting. But then what's the point of using futures altogether?

Comment: That's certainly a workable solution, but yeah, then why use futures at all.

Comment: Behaviour is changing with multiple invocation so a state is introduced in `getOrCreateResult`.We might need to store the state as `future` may or may not get called.So ensuring that 1st thread created a future does not gurantee createResult will be called.There will always be a race condition if we have different `future` returned.Might have to use concurrentcollection to hold the state or re-design.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try the form of the singleton pattern ([Lazy initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Lazy_initialization)).

Such as:

```java
private volatile ListenableFuture<Result> resultFuture;

public ListenableFuture<Result> getOrCreateResult() {
    if (resultFuture == null) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (resultFuture == null) {
                resultFuture = createResult();
            }
        }
    }
    return resultFuture;
}
```

Hope to help you.

Comment: This is more detailed. [Java Singleton Design Pattern Best Practices with Examples](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples)

Comment: Yes, good answer. The most important change is that all of the callers receive the _same_ `ListenableFuture` instance, rather than creating one on each call before the result is computed, which causes the race condition in the original code. There should be no side effects in `buildResult()`.

Comment: I may have oversimplified my example too much, but suppose `getOrCreateResult(Input)` took a parameter `Input` and the `Result` depends on the input. Would a singleton pattern still work if there's more than 1 `resultFuture`? And `Input` is high cardinality, basically an `UUID`

Comment: It won't work anymore, but I suggest you use `ConcurrentHashMap<Input, ListenableFuture<Result>>`.@kane